# crash when free pointer to function

Tags: c

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct test {
    int                                 action;
    void                                *data;
    void (*function)(int, void*);
} test;

int execute_func(void(*function)(int a, void *d), int action, void *data)
{
    struct test             *todo;

    todo = calloc (1,sizeof(struct test));
    if (todo == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    todo->action = action;
    todo->data = data;
    todo->function = function;
    todo->function(todo->action, todo->data);
    return 0;
}
```

After executing the function, i want to free the allocated structure usinf the following:

```
if(todo != NULL)
{
    if(todo->data != NULL)
    {
        free(todo->data);
    }
    if(todo->function != NULL)
    {
        free(todo->function); //Cause a crash
    }
    free(todo);
}
```

but i get a crash.

Comment: Why not simply `free(todo)` ?

Comment: I'm not an expert but are you allowed to free a function ?

Comment: `function` (RHS in `todo->function = function;`) is probably not something you allocated with `malloc` (its friends). So, you can't call free on it. Basically, you can't *free()* anything that you didn't allocate with one of the `*alloc` functions.

Comment: @SuperPeanut, no you are not.

Comment: Why are you freeing a function? It's already there. You didn't allocate it.

Comment: i used the calloc to allocate memory for the whole structure, i have to free the whole struct to avoid memory leak after the execution of the function

Comment: Moreover, why are you freeing something you did not allocate yourself? Your users may pass any sort of data, which they may have allocated in a multitude of ways. You can't reasonably decide that `free` is the proper deallocation function.  If you want to free everything, ask the users for a callback to free their data.

Comment: Didn't your compiler yell at you for even *trying* to free a function pointer?

Comment: @EOF How would the compiler know? A function pointer may get implicitly converted to the void pointer that `free` expects. I don't think any compilers on the market are so advanced that they sanity check the type of the data passed to the free function specifically. Some static analysers might, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @Lundin *object pointers* are implicitly converted to `void*`. Not *function pointers*.

Comment: @EOF Hmm ok void pointer conversion might be one of the "common extensions" cases. I'd have to double-check with the standard.

Comment: @Lundin: As far as I can tell, if `free()` is defined with a prototype, then attempting to `free()` a function pointer is a *constraint violation* and the compiler is *required* to issue a diagnostic message. However, both `gcc` and `clang` seem to only fulfill this requirement is invoked with `-Wpedantic`, which I find scandalous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only can free memory that have been allocated with `malloc`. So, you can't free function. A function pointer stores address from static memory.

```
if(todo != NULL)
{
    if(todo->data != NULL)
    {
        free(todo->data);
    }
    free(todo);
}
```

Also, same remark for `data`: you have to free it only *and only if* memory pointed by `data` have been dynamically allocated with `malloc`.

And to a more generic point of view, only free dynamically allocated memory if you are owner of it.

To answer of one of OP comments, when you use `calloc` to your structure, you allocate memory for structure only: an `int` and two pointer. You don't have allocated memory for function nor for memory pointed by data. To avoid memory leak, you just have to free memory from your structure, *ie* an `int` and two pointer (and not for pointed memory, because you don't know how they had been allocated)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are not allocated at runtime. In fact *you never must free function pointers!* **Trying to free a function pointer invokes undefined behaviour.**

You must free only what you allocated. Your freeing code is overmotivated and frees fields which were not allocated by your code. For all you know data may be a pointer to an object in global or automatic (i.e. stack) storage so it's ill conceived to free that.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple: you can only `free()` what you have previously allocated with `malloc`/`calloc`. If you didn't call `malloc`/`calloc` for a certain item, you can't `free` it or the program will crash.

Good program design dictates that together with your "execute_func" (which could do with a more meaningful name) there should also be a corresponding clean-up function where `free` is located.

And if you check a pointer against NULL, you must 1) make sure that all pointers are initialized to NULL, and 2) set every pointer to NULL after calling `free` for that pointer.

As a side note, `free` has well-defined behavior if you pass a null pointer to it: it will then do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't free a function pointer.

Only pointers returned by `malloc()` or similar functions can or have to be freed.

A function pointer simply points to a piece of static memory holding the function, you do not need to free it. Only dynamically allocated memory has to be freed.

More points of contention:

- Freeing a pointer doesn't set the variable holding the pointer to NULL, you have to do that yourself if you want to use it in a conditional check
- Freeing NULL will not crash your program, but do nothing instead (["If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/))