# What happens if we call free() for function pointer?

Tags: c++, c

I'm learning about function pointer via [this page](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/).

As I know, `free()` function accepts `void *` pointer, just as `malloc()` returns. Since function pointers are also just pointer, I've just got curious.

Is it possible, or legal to call `free()` for function pointers? If so, what happens?

Comment: If you do that civilization will end in a world of fire.

Comment: C - constraint violation, C++ - ill-formed

Comment: UB. Anything. Nothing. Computer explodes. Cursor stops flashing.

Comment: All these answers are nice and informative, but the only correct answer is "nothing".

Comment: Please don't ask "so what actually happens with UB" - the whole point is that it is undefined. If the question could usefully be answered, the answer would define the behaviour. UB means "you did something so stupid we're not going to check for it or even try enumerating the things that may break as a result. Everything is ruined and it's all your fault"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was illegal and UB.

Comment: In C **function pointer object** is different from **void pointer object**, and while on most implementation relaxed compiler allows conversion between them, this is not a general case. On systems where a function pointer is a **trap object** you'll crash the process. Said that passing a **wrong pointer of any type** to the `free()` function is UB.

Comment: Please do not ask about C or C++ but decide on one language. These are different languages, requiring different answers. IMHO one should need moderator approval for questions which contain both tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [crash when free pointer to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785869/crash-when-free-pointer-to-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which **must have been returned by a previous call** to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)` has already been called before, **undefined behavior** occurs.

**Undefined behavior** means anything can happen, so don't do that. When programming in C or C++ we want to stay in the realm of defined behavior.

Comment: you don't even get that far -- there is no implicit conversion from function pointer to `void *`

Comment: @MyBug18 Because C and C++ are so unrestricted, you can actually access areas on your computer which you usually shouldnt access. Like when you have an array of lets say 5 elements and you try to fetch/write the 6th (nonexistent) element, you may touch something outside of the boundaries and - when youre unlucky - destroy vital parts of your computer.

Comment: @Sunburst275 you will certainly not *"destroy vital parts of your computer"*. The OS knows how to help itself. Moreover those kind of accesses are UB, so the program may also do nothing at all if you go out of bounds.

Comment: @Timo yes of course the IDE and even the OS have safety features and know how to handle such things. No one is left unrestricted anymore, these days. What is UB, if I may ask?

Comment: @Sunburst275 _"...What is UB, if I may ask?"_:   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @rustyx How to check whether a pointer has already been freed? `ptr == null` ?

Comment: @Sunburst275 you can't.  Don't use raw pointers (except as observers). Use `std::unique_ptr` when you want the pointer to own the memory (or resource).  Have a read of https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Comment: @RichardCritten I somehow figured that already. Thank you for your input! I will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Answering for the C language:

Calling `free()` with a non-null pointer that was not initially by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `strdup()` or one another function explicitly documented as returning heap memory has undefined behavior.

If the function pointer points to an actual function, passing it as an argument to `free()` has undefined behavior.

If function pointers have the same representation as `void` pointers, passing a null function pointer might be harmless, but this behavior is not guaranteed by the C Standard. Similarly, if you store a pointer returned by `malloc()` into a function pointer, passing that to `free()` might work and deallocate the memory, but again the C Standard does not guarantee this behavior and there is really no good use case for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

`free` can only be used on pointers previously allocated by `malloc` (or on `nullptr` in which case it does nothing). It doesn't matter if the argument is a variable on the stack, an object with static storage, or a function pointer (but converting a function pointer to `void*` does not have to be supported on every platform). If you do it, [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) follows.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers do not convert to or from `void*` implicitly in C++. Thus directly passing a function pointer to `free` won't work. So, this is as close to what you ask as you can legally get:

```
void (*ptr)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(std::malloc(1));
free(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr));
```

> If so, what happens?

The memory that you got from malloc is freed. If you attempted to pass any other non-null pointer, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Also, converting function pointer to or from `void*` is only conditionally supported - such conversion may be ill-formed in some implementations.

Furthermore, this is quite pointless, since `malloc` won't ever return the address of any function.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers say you'll get an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Undefined behavior means anything can happen. It means also it can work fine, but you cannot guarantee that. Your program might fail later in time, and it's hard to debug. It's one of the (many) pitfalls of C++, and it's one of the reasons many programmers prefer other languages like Python, Java or C#.

Here is a safer alternative in C++11 or newer: learn and use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)
With std::function, you catch errors at compile-time instead of 10 years after delivering your product (I've actually seen that in my career)